# JPA persist cascade failing on lazy fetch field

Tags: jpa, lazy-evaluation, cascade, openjpa

Here is a strange thing I have noticed while using jpa. I am using openjpa 1.0, RAD 8.0 and WAS 6.1(no I can not use jpa 2).

I have a class ProductArrangement and within that class a list of Accounts. Within an Account I have a list of Statements. When I create the initial productArrangement with an initial account and an initial statement the persist works flawlessly. Everything is properly stored in the DB.

When later I want to add a statement to the account in the productArrangement, that I got access to with a find, the persist had no result in accounts or in the statements. The changes in productArrangement were succesful. However when I did a getAccount().getStatements() before the getAccount().addStatement(statement) then it works fine. How is this possible? Is it because its lazy fetch that I have to do a get before?

Comment: The lazy fetch shouldn't be the issue because when you call addStatement, the lazy collection should be populated.  Please post the code for your ProductArrangement, Account, and Statement classes.

Answer (score 0):

*> Is it because its lazy fetch that I have to do a get before?*

Err... yes and no.
Yes: it seems lazy load is not occurring, so you have a bug.
No: it may not be a bug in the providers code, but may be a bug in your code for `addAccount()` and `addStatement()`.

Adding new account(s) or statement(s) should mean navigating the relationships to these collections of entities.  It should automatically trigger any lazy load, so this shouldn't be the cause of your error.

However, you need to navigate the relationships by **calling the getter methods to trigger lazy loading automatically from within your entity**.  Directly accessing the instance fields within your entity will never trigger lazy loading - this would be a bug in your code, not the JPA providers.

*> However when I did a getAccount().getStatements() before the getAccount().addStatement(statement) then it works fine.*

Maybe your method looks like this:

```
 public class Account {

     // fields and methods ...

     public void addStatement(Statement s) {
          this.statementsCollection.add(s);
     }
 }
```

If so, that's a bug for lazy loading.  It should look like this:

```
 public class Account {

     // fields and methods ...

     public void addStatement(Statement s) {
          this.getStatements().add(s);
     }
 }
```

i.e. then your external client/test code wouldn't need to artificially call getAccount().getStatements(), because the internal code of addStatement does it automatically.

:-D